# another data in mutablelivedata returning empty

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelivedata

another data in mutablelivedata
I want. But normally running function doesn't work inside this function

```
fun getFirebaseBasketList(): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<BikeBasketModel>> {
        database.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                bikeArray = ArrayList()
                for (postSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val gson = Gson()
                    val json: String = postSnapshot.value.toString()
                    val bikeBasketModel : BikeBasketModel = gson.fromJson(json, BikeBasketModel::class.java)
                    checkAndAdd(bikeBasketModel,bikeArray)
                }
                mutableLiveData.value = bikeArray
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
        return mutableLiveData
    }
```

here the data is empty when i call it with getFirebaseBasketList()

```
    fun getTotalFee() : MutableLiveData<Int> {
        var totalCount = 0
        val mutableLiveDataInt : MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()

        bikeArray = getFirebaseBasketList().value ?: ArrayList()

        if (bikeArray.isEmpty())
            return mutableLiveDataInt

        bikeArray.forEach { totalCount += it.bikePrice * it.bikeCount }
        mutableLiveDataInt.value = totalCount
        return mutableLiveDataInt
    }
```

Comment: replace ".value = " with ".postValue()"

Comment: ValueEventListener is called some time in the future so your are checking for the live data value before it has been set. See here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o

Comment: You shouldn't use LiveData in place of callbacks anyway. That is very convoluted. A LiveData is for observing, usually in perpetuity on a lifecycle, not for getting a single value out of it.